# search all in same query

Tags: php, html, mysql

table (book) ==> (keyid,name)

```
<form action="se.php">
    <select>
    <option value="1">book1</option>
    <option value="2">book2</option>
    <option value="3">book3</option>
    <option value="????">All Book</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
</form>

//se.php 
    $keyid=$_GET[keyid];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `book` WHERE `keyid`='$keyid'");
//end page
```

what i put in last option value (????) for sql query search all content???

Comment: Should it be posting and not $_GET[keyid] mhm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all

then:

```
$where = '';

if $keyid != all then {
  $where = WHERE `keyid`= $keyid // escape value protect from sql injection!
}

mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `book` $where");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$keyid=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[keyid]);
if(trim($keyid)!="")
    $where = " `keyid`='$keyid' ";
else
    $where = " 1 ";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `book` WHERE $where ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very weak about protecting from sql injection. You should escape your inputs and never trust the values that you receive. Think about this value in your option:

```
<option value="';truncate table book;">All Book</option>
```

A good approach is the answer by @cojack